# Make elements align on media screen changed

Tags: html, css

I have two divs which change their position when the x axis or y axis of the screen is higher or smaller than the other axis. You can test that in the JsFiddle example.

[JSFIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/czQTT)

My ButtonToolbar elements position gets messed up when the position of the two divs is changed. How to fix this positioning issue?

I'v tried using position `position:relative` but didn't manage to get it working. Any ideas? Hope you understand my problem.

Comment: Are you saying that they should be in a line when on top instead of a column?

Comment: Yes. I'm talking about the green elements!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `position:relative` try `float:left` on `.dhFieldset` when shown on top of a screen.

```
@media screen and (max-aspect-ratio: 1/1) { 
    .dhFieldset{
      color: white; 
      height: 35px;
      width:80px;
      margin-left:22px;
      float:left;
}
```

Also, if you do not want them to go one below other - you will need to set `min-width` on `.dhButtonToolbar`. Like it is done [here](http://jsfiddle.net/czQTT/4/)
Or you can change a width of dhFieldset to percentage width.

Answer (score 2):

Let's hope i got what your problem was. In the media query you should change the way the "dhFieldset" are shown.

So it would go like this:

**Normal Position:**

```
.dhFieldset{
   color: white;
   font-size:6px;
   width: 27px;
   height:80px;
   background-color:green;

}
```

**In the top of the screen:**

```
@media screen and (max-aspect-ratio: 1/1) { 
.dhFieldset{
   color: white;
   font-size:6px;
   height: 27px;
   width:80px;
   margin-left:22px;
   float:left;   
}
```

Here is the [Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/czQTT/1/).

Hope it helps!!
Cheers.